# Using if and else with combineLatest in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a return statement having combineLatest, which calls two functions inside. I want to add if and else block for those functions, but I have failed to do so, till now.

```
return combineLatest([
  this.firstfunction();
  this.secondfunction()
]).pipe(
  map(_ => Success()),
  catchError(error => {
    return error
  })
);
```

I want to have if().... this.firstfunction() and another if().. this.secondfunction().. Currently, it gives error, when I add the if block inside the combineLatest. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's not clear what your expected behaviour is, please clarify so we can propose a valid solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
const observables = [];
if(conditionForFirstFuction) {
    observables.push(this.firstFunction());
}
if(conditionForSecondFunction) {
    observables.push(this.secondFunction());
}

return combineLatest(observables).pipe(
    map(_ => Success()),
    catchError(error => {
        return error
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see what you want, but you can try this using the spread operator. Be aware though if you end up with an empty array, when both conditions are false, the `combineLatest` will never fire:

```
return combineLatest([
  ...( firstCondition ? this.firstfunction() : [] ),
  ...( secondCondition ? this.secondfunction() : [] )
]).pipe(
  map(_ => Success())
);
```